# Is it possible to plot a second-order curve by its non-canonical equation?

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I have this second-order polynom:

$$
6xy+8y^2-12x-26y+11=0
$$

And I need to reduce it to a canonical form of a second-order curve. I solved this, but is it possible to draw a plot of the original equation to check whether my solution is correct? Something like

```
Plot[6 x*y + 8 y^2 - 12 x - 26 y + 11, {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {-20, 20}]
```

Now this draws an empty plot.

Thank you.

Comment: Look up `ContourPlot`. Also, you need a space between `x` and `y`, otherwise it denotes a different variable named `xy`.

Comment: @RahulNarain thank you for spotting `xy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @[Rahul](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul-narain) said in a comment (beat me to it!), have a look at [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html):

```
ContourPlot[
  6 x y + 8 y^2 - 12 x - 26 y + 11 == 0, 
  {x, -20, 20},
  {y, -20, 20}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: could you suggest how can I draw the x and y axes on this plot, please?

Comment: @user5693 Then you can give the option `FrameLabel`: `ContourPlot[...., FrameLabel -> Automatic]`. This is actually given in the documentation (admittedly buried a bit, but still).

Comment: sorry, my question was incorrect to some point. I meant to set axes origin at 0,0, is it possible? Google says nothing

Comment: @user5693 Ah sorry I misunderstood; that's `ContourPlot[..., Axes -> True, Frame -> False]`. (Can also be found in the documentation of ContourPlot!).